# VBA function to alert when value is changed within a time frame

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel cell where its value is updated every minute.

What I need is an alert message box; while that cell value moves to a particular time.

Suppose a cell has value 10:

- if it reaches 7 in one minute then I need a message box to alert that.
- if it is not reaching 7 in one minute then I don't need any alert.

Please help write me a macro for this.

Comment: You probably know this already, but one could surmise that this Excel document possibly should become an Access database.

Answer (score 5):

Inside VBA editor for ThisWorkBook, you could write the following code

```
Dim WithEvents SheetToWatch As Worksheet

Private Sub SheetToWatch_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$A$2" Then
    If Target.Value = 7 Then
        MsgBox "changed to 7"
    End If
End If
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set SheetToWatch = Sheets("Sheet1")
End Sub
```

Basically the code sets the reference of Sheet1 to the variable `SheetToWatch` when the workbook opens. Declaring the variable using `WithEvents` lets one capture the events.

I am using `Change` event of the worksheet and checking if the cell that was changed is A2. If so, I am checking or comparing the value with 7 (it can be dynamic and depends on how you want to handle it).

See if this helps.

Comment: SheetActivate fires when the sheet get focus, not when its data changes, doesn't it?

Comment: @RBarryYoung: You are right. I added that extra piece of code by mistake. I will edit it now. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Cannot be done with a function, any way that I can think of.

If you control the mechanism that is updating the cell, then you could it call a VBA subroutine that you wrote, instead, have to send the alert and then update the cell from that routine.

If you do not control the updating mechanism, then the only thing that I can think of that might work is of the Cell, Range or Worksheet classes have a ChangedDate event that you could catch from VBA and do your alerting from there.